# File format to convert legacy data

Tags: python, json, file-format, legacy

I have a huge amount of files that are structured like this:

```
// NAME = XXXX
// MARKER = YYYY
// SOURCE = ZZZZ
# Real data follows, one item per line
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

I'm trying to move out of this legacy format because it's a bother to parse (sometimes there are 3 // lines, sometimes 4): given that the Item1, etc... lists are not long (max 400 items or so) I was thinking of a suitable replacement. The absolute necessity would be to be text-based.

I had in mind two ideas:

1. Use JSON
2. Keep the data as is but condense the header on one single line

The goals are however to *avoid* custom parsing as much as possible (the main issue for these files) and rely on built parsers (Python ones in my specific case).
Assuming I go for 1, is JSON actually an appropriate choice?

Comment: What about conf-files? http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Comment: @defuz I find INI syntax for this specific type of file problematic because of the length of Item1,Item2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some reasons in favor of JSON:

- It is human readable
- It is not as verbose as XML
- Python has a [built-in library](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) for reading/writing JSON
- JSON is not Python-specific (unlike [configparser](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/configparser.html)). Other languages
  can also parse JSON

One possible problem with JSON:

- The whole JSON must be read to be parsed. This may be a (memory) problem
  if the JSON is huge.

Comment: It's not going to be "huge" per se, since the list of Item1,.. will be less than 1000 at maximum.

Answer (score 2):

In an enterprise environment, my preference would be XML due to its mature validation options, data type specifications and non-unicode support.

I understand JSON also has a draft Schema spec which would be worth using if you go down the JSON route.